# Reusing the custom list in all the activities

Tags: android

In my course app I have list of courses with sub courses. courses are display in custom-list. once the user click the course title.particular course activity will be open with the details of the course. Inside that activity "course content" text view with click listener.once the user click that text view a custom list with sub courses of the particular course will be open. I tried to use same custom list for all sub courses in every course. instead of creating separate custom list for every course. I tried to achieve this by sending image array and courseTitle array from course activity to custom list activity through Intent. but while clicking the course content text view the custom list activity stopped unfortunately.Here the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTine.png)

**BigdataActivity (course activity)**

```
public class BigdataActivity extends Activity {

ImageView logo;
Button phone,mail,whatsapp;
TextView course;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bigdata);

    logo=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) logo.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = 350; params.height=150; params.leftMargin=150;
    logo.setLayoutParams(params);
    course=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.course);
    phone=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mail=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    whatsapp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    course.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //MyAlert alert=new MyAlert();
            //alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "Fill the Form");

            int activity=1;
            Resources res=getResources();
            String[] courseTitle=res.getStringArray(R.array.BigData);
            int image[] =
            {
              R.drawable.bigdatahad,
              R.drawable.hadoopadmin,R.drawable.bigdataanalytics,
              R.drawable.testing
            };
            Intent intent=new   
            Intent(BigdataActivity.this,BDataDialog.class);
            intent.putExtra("img", image);
            intent.putExtra("course", courseTitle);
            intent.putExtra("activity", activity);
            startActivity(intent);





        }


    });
    phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String no="+9187";
            Intent callintent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+no));
            startActivity(callintent);

        }
    });

    mail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent mailintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mailintent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            String[] toadd={"info@jpasolutions.in"};
            mailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,toadd);
            mailintent.setType("message/rfc822");
            Intent chooser = mailintent.createChooser(mailintent, "Send 
            Email");
            startActivity(chooser);
        }
    });

    whatsapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String cont="7290";
            openWhatsappContact(cont);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bigdata, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.action_settings){

        startActivityForResult(new 
        Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


void openWhatsappContact(String number) {


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));

}
```

}

**Custom list activity to list sub courses**

public class BDataDialog extends Activity {

```
ImageView logoview;
ListView list;
String[] courseTitle=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("course");
int image[]=getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("img");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bdata_dialog);
    //logoview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


   // list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   /* Resources res=getResources();
    courseTitle=res.getStringArray(R.array.BData);*/
    CourseAdapter listAdapter =new CourseAdapter(this, courseTitle, image);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
            int activity =getIntent().getIntExtra("activity", 0);

            if (value == courseTitle[0]){

                switch(activity){
                case 1:
                    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.jpasolutions.net/coursedetails.php?cat_id=1&crs_id=1&sub_id=1"); 
                    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
                    startActivity(launchBrowser);   
                    finish();
                    break;
                case 2:

                    Uri uriUrl1 = Uri.parse("http://www.jpasolutions.net/coursedetails.php?cat_id=1&crs_id=24&sub_id=1"); 
                    Intent launchBrowser1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl1);  
                    startActivity(launchBrowser1);   
                    finish();
                    break;
                }


            }
            else{

                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.jpasolutions.net/coursedetails.php?cat_id=1&crs_id=32&sub_id=1"); 
                Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
                startActivity(launchBrowser);   
                finish();
            }



        }



    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bdata_dialog, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

class CourseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
Context context; int images[];String titleArray[];
CourseAdapter(Context ctx,String[] courseTitle, int imgs[])
{
    super(ctx,R.layout.courseslist,R.id.textView1,courseTitle);
    this.context=ctx;
    this.images=imgs;
    this.titleArray=courseTitle;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) 
     context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.courseslist, parent, false);

     ImageView myimage=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     TextView  textview=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     myimage.setImageResource(images[position]);
     textview.setText(titleArray[position]);

    return row;
}
```

}

pls help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your `getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("course")` is returning null...

Try to:

- Handle this getIntent() events inside `oncreate`.
- Validate when you put extras on intent, before launch activity, if
  they're are not null